# What type of romanization is "Hatchōbori"?

Tags: rōmaji

I found somewhere on the internet that the romanization of 八丁堀{はっちょうぼり} is written as "Hatchōbori".

1. Given that scheme, how could you write "しゅっぱつ"?
2. Given that scheme, how could you write "しゅぱつ"?
3. What is the name of that romanization scheme?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an example of [Hepburn romanization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hepburn_romanization), which attempts to represent Japanese according to how it is pronounced. With geminated っち, it's standard to use tch instead of a double c, so instead of "maccha" you would write "matcha" for 抹茶. Similarly, long vowels use a macron (bar) instead of doubling, so "Hatchōbori" instead of "Hatchoobori."

出発{しゅっぱつ} is "shuppatsu." しゅぱつ (not a word) would be "shupatsu."